# Two headers in Report Service for C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, header, rdlc

I'm trying to create a report for my project with a specific template. Having three groups, lets call it Apartment, Building and Dwellers.

We have 6 buildings. Each building contains 20 apartments and each apartment contains N dwellers.

The report I'm trying to create follows this template :

## Building A

### Dwellers |  Apartments

Dweller A    |       Apartment 1
   Dweller B    |     Apartment 1
   Dweller C    |     Apartment 2
   Dweller D    |     Apartment 3

## Building B

### Dwellers |  Apartments

Dweller E    |     Apartment 1
   Dweller F    |     Apartment 2
   Dweller G    |     Apartment 2
   Dweller H    |     Apartment 3

Is it possible to do something like this using Report Service from Visual Studio 2010 ?

Comment: What have you [tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this within a grid (tablix?) you could create respective groupings. Another solution would be to use a `List` and group it by building. Then, within the `List` you are free to layout using other controls.

Comment: You mean I can put other controls and give priorities to them inside the list ?

Comment: What do you mean by "priorities"? Think of a `List` as a report element that is data bound (is repeated per record - when grouped, per group) and allows you to put other controls inside it, for example text boxes, grids, etc.

Comment: Sorry for such a delayed message, but I got really stuck at work and couldn't do anything else beside work and sleep. I seem to understand by reading your last comment. Thanks for the attention. :)